# Generate numbers from 2 to 10,000. The numbers printed can only be a multiple of 2 prime numbers

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

Homework: I'm just stumped as hell. I have algorithms set up, but I have no idea how to code this

Just to be clear you do not need arrays or to pass variables by reference.

The purpose of the project is to take a problem apart and using Top-Down_Design or scratch pad method develop the algorithm.

Problem:

Examine the numbers from 2 to 10000. Output the number if it is a Dual_Prime.

I will call a DualPrime a number that is the product of two primes.  Ad where the two primes are not equal .   So 9 is not a dual prime.   15 is ( 3 * 5 ) . 
The output has 10 numbers on each line.

My Algorithm set-up

Step 1: find prime numbers.:

```
bool Prime_Number(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if (number % 1 == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Step 2: store prime numbers in a array

Step 3: Multiply each array to each other

```
void Multiply_Prime_Numbers(int Array[], int Size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Size- 1; j++)
    {
        Dual_Prime[] =  Arr[j] * Arr[j + 1]  
    }
}
```

Step 4: Bubble sort

```
void Bubble_Sort(int Array[], int Size) // Sends largest number to the right
{
    for (int i = Size - 1; i > 0; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (Array[j] > Array[j + 1])
            {
                int Temp = Array[j + 1];
                Array[j + 1] = Array[j];
                Array[j] = Temp;
            }
}
```

Step 5: Display New Array by rows of 10

```
void Print_Array(int Array[], int Size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        cout << Dual_Prime[i] << (((j % 10) == 9) ? '\n' : '\t');
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `Prime_Number` is going to be awesomely slow (`sqrt(number)` is very slow) and I don't think it'll work (`number % 1 == 0` doesn't feel right). Look into using a (incoming search term!)  Prime Number Sieve.

Comment: I haven't learned dynamic arrays yet, so I can't use the sieve of eratosthenes

Comment: You don't need dynamic allocation. You can make a big, whacking `static` variable or global, not that 10,000 is particularly big.

Comment: I would go with @user4581301: After having an array with all primes, you could simply multiply any pair of them. This would reduce to two nested `for` loops (considering that second must always be greater than first to prevent duplicated results). As every result is the product of a unique pair of prime factors, thus, there cannot be an "accidental" duplicate in output. (What a nice fact - no post-check needed.) ;-)

Comment: `Dual_Prime[] =  Arr[j] * Arr[j + 1]` This will not work. I just got an idea, how to eliminate the need for this (and for the bubble sort step): You could make an array `bool dualPrimes[10000]{};` (Don't forget that array indexing starts with 0 - be careful concerning off-by-1 errors.) Then you can "mark" every number which was recognized as dual prime: `dualPrimes[prod - 1] = true;` (when `prod` stores the current dual prime product). Finally, you just loop through this array and output the index + 1 for every "marked" element of `dualPrimes` (similar to what you already did for last step).

Comment: Is the objective of this assignment to find prime numbers, or to evaluate prime numbers?  If it's just to evaluate, I'd use a static array of primes, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel of finding primes.

Comment: I'm not going to answer your question, but I get a list of 2600 semi-primes (the mathematician's name for what you called dual primes) less than 10000 starting with 2 * 3 = 6 and ending with 2 * 4999 = 9998.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Ex10_TwoPrimes.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.


#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Homework_Header(string Title);
void Do_Exercise();
void Sieve_Of_Eratosthenes(int n);
void Generate_Semi_Prime();

bool Semi_Prime(int candidate);
bool prime[5000 + 1];

int main()
{
    Do_Exercise();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void Do_Exercise()
{
    int n = 5000;

    Sieve_Of_Eratosthenes(n);

    cout << endl;

    Generate_Semi_Prime();
}

void Sieve_Of_Eratosthenes(int n)
{
    // Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize 
    // all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will 
    // finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true. 

    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

    for (int p = 2; p*p <= n; p++)
    {
        // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime 
        if (prime[p] == true)
        {
            // Update all multiples of p 
            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }
    }
}

bool Semi_Prime(int candidate)
{
    for (int index = 2; index <= candidate / 2; index++)
    {
        if (prime[index])
        {
            if (candidate % index == 0)
            {
                int q = candidate / index;
                if (prime[q] && q != index)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Generate_Semi_Prime()
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 10000; i++)
        if (Semi_Prime(i)) cout << i << "\t";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't learned dynamic arrays yet,

Although dynamic arrays and the sieve of Eratosthenes are more preferable, I tried to write **minimally** fixed version of your code.

First, we define following global variables which are used in your original implementation of `Multiply_Prime_Numbers`.
([**Please check this post.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad))

```
constexpr int DP_Size_Max = 10000;
int DP_Size = 0;
int Dual_Prime[DP_Size_Max];
```

Next we fix `Prime_Number` as follows.
The condition `number%1==0` in the original code is not appropriate:

```
bool Prime_Number(int number)
{
    if(number<=1){
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i*i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In addition, `Multiply_Prime_Numbers` should be implemented by double for-loops as follows:

```
void Multiply_Prime_Numbers(int Array[], int Size)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < Size; ++j)
        {
            Dual_Prime[DP_Size] = Array[i]*Array[j];

            if(Dual_Prime[DP_Size] >= DP_Size_Max){
                return;
            }

            ++DP_Size;
        }        
    }
}
```

Then these functions work as follows.
[**Here's a DEMO of this minimally fixed version.**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0I5LOP7VWK3uIINZ)

```
int main()
{
    int prime_numbers[DP_Size_Max];
    int size = 0;

    for(int j=2; j<DP_Size_Max; ++j)
    {
        if(Prime_Number(j)){
            prime_numbers[size]=j;
            ++size;
        }
    }

    Multiply_Prime_Numbers(prime_numbers, size);
    Bubble_Sort(Dual_Prime, DP_Size);

    for(int i=0; i<DP_Size;++i){
        std::cout << Dual_Prime[i] << (((i % 10) == 9) ? '\n' : '\t');;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a known algorithm which speeds up the search of all the primes up to a certain number.

The OP can use it to implement the first steps of their implementation, but they can also adapt it to avoid the sorting step.

Given the list of all primes (up to half the maximum number to examine):

- Create an array of bool as big as the range of numbers to be examined.
- Multiply each distinct couple of primes, using two nested loops.
- If the product is less than 10000 (the maximum) set the corrisponding element of the array to  true. Otherwise break out the inner loop.
- Once finished, traverse the array and if the value is true, print the corresponding index.

Here there's a [proof of concept](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eAj5HQeAub0DJgkc) (implemented without the OP's assignment restrictions).